# Windows 7 and two BIND9 nameservers

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-7, bind

The setup:

- Two BIND9 nameservers (running on Debian 9.6)
- Windows 7 workstations as DHCP clients, the two nameservers acquired via DHCPD (`option domain-name-servers 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2;`)

Now, at least once a strange thing happened: one of the nameservers went down with a box going down, and all of a sudden all Windows 7 workstations lost DNS resolution completely. It's a situation the same as described in intro in https://morgansimonsen.com/2012/07/03/will-if-fail-over-or-just-fail-some-dns-empirical-testing/.

I have done a similar test **later** (after the incident): let Windows 7 acquire two nameservers, shut down one of them a few seconds afterwards and tested name resolution via `nslookup` and a browser opening some internet websites.

`nslookup` got lost completely, unable to resolve anything, but browser continued to function.

It may have been in the initial case that quite some time passed between one nameserver going down and workstations losing name resolution.

Why has this happened? And how do I ensure that this does not happen again?

Am I forced to keep using just a single nameserver for Win7 clients?

Comment: Windows client DNS resolution is quite...wobbly. Have a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2834226/net-dns-dns-client-resolution-timeouts , specifically **What is the default behavior of a Windows 7 or Windows 8 DNS client when two DNS servers are configured on the NIC?**

Comment: If one name server goes down and the other does not take over, perhaps we need the config of the two name servers in order to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> - all Windows 7 workstations lost DNS resolution completely.
> - `nslookup` got lost completely, unable to resolve anything, but browser
>     continued to function.

These statements are conflicting. This happens, because [`nslookup`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/nslookup) is a diagnostics tool:

> Displays information that you can use to diagnose Domain Name System
>   (DNS) infrastructure. Before using this tool, you should be familiar
>   with how DNS works.

Normally a program calls e.g. [`DnsQuery_A()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Windns/nf-windns-dnsquery_a) function with `DNS_QUERY_STANDARD` option. The resolver first checks from its local cache (including names specified in the `hosts` file) and then tries to use all the DNS servers in order. If the name wasn't cached and the first server(s) is down, the DNS resolution takes longer.

But, **as a diagnostics tool, `nslookup` omits the `hosts` file and chooses the first *default server* unless you manually pick another DNS server**.

```
Usage:
   nslookup [-opt ...]             # interactive mode using default server
   nslookup [-opt ...] - server    # interactive mode using 'server'
```

During the session you can change the server to see which server is down. In your environment the following test session could have indicated the problem with server `10.0.0.1`:

```
Default Server:  [10.0.0.1]
Address:  10.0.0.1

> google.com
Server:  [10.0.0.1]
Address:  10.0.0.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to [10.0.0.1] timed-out
```

even when the resolution works as the `10.0.0.2` is still answering:

```
> server 10.0.0.2
Default Server:  [10.0.0.2]
Address:  10.0.0.2

> google.com
Server:  [10.0.0.2]
Address:  10.0.0.2

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:400f:80d::200e
          216.58.211.142
```

Comment: Re "These statements are conflicting." Your first bullet point effectively describes the incident I've had in production. The second bullet point refers to the test I've done afterwards. Anyway, thanks for explanation on `nslookup`.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a minute and don't test that with nslookup. Windows (7) nslookup binds to one server at process start and does not change that by itself. Close CMD, wait a while (default ist 300 seconds) and try again.

Comment: Ack about the nslookup, but I think users called me after longer than 5 minutes and DNS resolution on all the workstations was still dead.